# Life Hacks: Teacher Edition!

Tags: teaching, time-management

Now that I've gotten your attention with that terrible title...

The Mathematical Association of America used to regularly run a column called Teaching Time Savers, an archive of which can be found here: http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/teaching-and-learning/teaching-time-savers

These articles offer tips on things like:

- How to reduce time spent grading
- How to influence students to study in a more effective manner
- Advice for streamlining the writing of recommendation letters

Note that many (most?) of these tips are not specific to a mathematics course.

**Are there any other collections of such articles floating around the web?**

Comment: Like [McKeachies Teaching Tips](http://www.amazon.com/McKeachies-Teaching-Tips-Wilbert-McKeachie/dp/1133936792) but you want it for free?

Comment: @earthling Thanks for bringing this book to my attention! But free is certainly preferable.

Comment: Tips like [How to improve your teaching evaluations](https://kingscollegecelt.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/how-to-improve-student-evaluations-of-your-teaching/)?

Comment: I'm really looking for things that make typical teacher duties (grading, office hours, etc) more efficient. Thanks, though.

Comment: This is probably much broader than the scope you're looking for, but I'm try to learn David Allen's *Getting Things Done* approach. The GTD Web site has some general principles, although they'll make more sense with the book in hand. It's not teaching-oriented but would probably make teachers more effective.

Comment: Free?  The library is your friend.

Comment: Fits better on [Matheducators.SE]?

Comment: @gerrit Most of the "teaching time savers" are not specific to mathematics and would be helpful in any discipline.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to search inside it for which tactics affect time efficiency, but "Tools for Teaching" by Barbara Gross Davis is a great compendium of pedagogical techniques, with citations to the research which justifies them. The main focus is doing it better, not doing it faster, but an astute reader can for sure find useful tricks in there.